# ubuntu server sending massive udp traffic to an ip

Tags: postfix

We have noticed that several of our ubuntu servers are sending massive amounts of udp traffic to an IP that we don't recognize. Could the server be infected? How can we find out? The servers have postfix installed on them. The only open ports on these machines are smtp and pop3.

Comment: Hard to know with such little information. capture the packets with at tool such as tcpdump

Answer (score 0):

UDP is used for a variety of services.   If you only have SMTP and POP3 open, you should have no UDP traffic.   I assume you also have DNS open on both TCP and UDP.   Massive amounts of traffic is a rather imprecise measurement.  Is it 1% of your traffic or bandwidth, or 90%.

If you allow incoming email, I would assume you are also running some sort of mail scanning software.  This should generate a fair number of DNS lookups.  For this reason, it is recommend that you run a caching DNS server on the host.  UDP is also used by some other resources used to identify spam.

The command `sudo netstat -anp | grep udp | grep less` will list connections using UDP and the associated program.  This may help identify the source of the traffic.  Repeating the command as `sudo netstat -anp | grep udp | grep EST | less` a few times could give you an idea if this is an ongoing connection.

You can use `tcpdump` to examine the traffic and determine what type of data is being passed.  This will give you an idea whether the traffic is legitmate.

Another tool you could use is `ntop` which will summarize traffic by protocol and host.  It can give you and idea what traffic is passing.

You can insert a blocking rule in the `iptables`.   This can block traffic by IP address, protocol, or protocol and port.  Be prepared to remove the rule quickly in case the traffic is legitimate.